# JavaScript / Jquery IE8 Issue, Click event on IE8 does not work, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

The problem I have is that the program I have is not working correctly in IE8 for some people. The website is an English course and in IE8 for some people you are unable to click on the correct answers. Take a look at the following video:http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cXllIjvxW

Take a look and you will see the user is trying to click but it is not working. Take a closer look yourself and login to http://www.fcecourse.com/grammar-fce?m=11  with the username *digital* and the password *digital*.  Then click on unit 1  (01) , then click on  exercise, then on start ...   here is another video: http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cXllD9v4D

The strange thing is that I have tested this and others have tested it and it is working fine in IE8, in windows 7, but other people I know are getting this problem are unable to click on the correct answers. I need a solution.

Comment: Can you post the code snippet?

Comment: hi, i dont know whats causing the problem

Comment: I get a JavaScript error as soon as the page loads (in IE8).

Comment: im aware of JavaScript erorrs, dont know if its causing this though

Comment: Well I'm able to click on answers.  And by the way may of those questions can be correctly answered with either answer. Not all of them, but some definitely can be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey i had like a couple of weeks ago the same problem and taking just a little look inside your html i see you have this:

```
<a onclick="javascript:comprobar('has', 'r-25529');" href="javascript:;">has</a>
```

the problem i had with internet explorer 7 and 8 was because i was calling my javascript function in the onload attribute of the anchore instead of bind the event with jquery and later do your stuff i fix this like this:

```
<a id="answer" href="javascript:;" number="25529" >has</a>
```

and later(Edited):

```
$('.answer').live('#answer', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var link_prefix = "r-"; //prefix of the link to check
    var link_number = $(this).attr('number'); //obtaining the number attribute from the link
    var completeLink = link_prefix + link_number;
    comprobar('has', completeLink);//the onclick stuff here
})
```

and that should be work on ie 7 and 8 i promise in this way you can obtain the value of the clicked link bassed in a class.

Comment: if the value r-25529 is chaning all the time, how can i do this?

Comment: Hey i edit the code if you take a look in the live event below i add a couple of variables to hold the value you want to get in that way you are going to be sure you are getting the desired value